# JPA - how to prevent an unnecessary join while querying many to many relationships

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, pagination, spring-data

I have entities Product and Category that are joined with a simple many to many relationship. I want to get a paginated list of products filtered by a single category. I'm trying to write a `Spring Data JPA` automatic method or a `JPQL` query method that would produce the `SQL` similar to the following:

```
select [...] FROM ProductToCategory ptc INNER JOIN Product p ON ptc.product_id=p.id WHERE ptc.category_id=?  LIMIT ? OFFSET ?
```

Since the `ProductToCategory` join table isn't a `JPA entity` and I can't reference it in `JPQL`, the closest thing I could come up with was:

```
@Query("SELECT p FROM Category c INNER JOIN c.products p WHERE c=:category")
Page<Product> findByCategories(@Param("category") Category category, Pageable pageable);
```

But the resulting `SQL` produces a redundant join with the Category table and applies the where clause there, instead of on category `id` in the `ProductToCategory` table. Is there a way to do this without resorting to native `SQL`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only way I can see is to map an entity to the join table and replace the many-to-many Product<>Category with one-to-many relationships pointing to this new entity from both Product and Category.

Such a change would actually be in line with Hibernate best practices:

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/best-practices.html

> **Do not use exotic association mappings**: 
>   Practical test cases for real
>   many-to-many associations are rare. Most of the time you need
>   additional information stored in the "link table". In this case, it is
>   much better to use two one-to-many associations to an intermediate
>   link class. In fact, most associations are one-to-many and
>   many-to-one. **For this reason, you should proceed cautiously when using
>   any other association style**.